# Angular v17 builder for github page publication

Tags: angular, deployment, github-pages

In angular v17 they use "application" builder . with this builder build file create with docs/browser. I am facing issues with this extra browser folder when i try to publishmy application in github pages.

I accepct either my application build with "browser" builder which was in previous builder . Or any other solution to publish angular v17 project in github page